# Is this a valid way to initialize static variables?

Tags: java, static-variables

I have a big file of constants. Is this a valid way to initialize them?

```
private static int i = 0;

public static final int ITEM_GOLD = i++;
public static final int ITEM_ZINC = i++;
public static final int ITEM_TIN = i++;
....
```

`ITEM_GOLD` should equal `0`, `ITEM_ZINC` should equal `1`, `ITEM_TIN` should equal `2` and so on.

Comment: Are you looking for `enum`?

Comment: In case you mean that metal that's spelled [zinc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc)

Comment: valid as in It Will Compile?  Sure.  If you ever need to know which constant corresponds to your thirty-fourth `static final int` you're going to be annoyed though :)

Comment: Why don't you try and see it by yourself ? Isn't that easier than posting your question here?

Comment: @sakthisundar I have tried it many times and it "works", but I want to finish this code and set it aside and not have to worry about any bugs popping up later because of some obscure anomaly in the way static variables work :)

Comment: @zapl *cough* hmm? ;)

Comment: I don't know why I've posted that comment. I guess I was dreaming :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this should work. However, I would recommend to use the enum class instead. If the number really has some semantic (not just an arbitrary discriminator of a constant) then this is ok, otherwise enum is better (can be used in switch, the code is more readable, etc..)

If you don't want to introduce a new file, you may want to declare the enum in the surrounding class:

```
public TheClass {
   ...
   enum Item {
     GOLD, ZYNC, TIN
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Specifically, JLS [12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) step 9 says that the class variable initializers are executed in textual order.

Comment: Well the purpose of using integers was that my items are divided into groups (e.g. `ITEM_STEEL` is of `TYPE_COMPOUND` and `ITEM_CEDAR` is of `TYPE_WOOD`). I keep track of the last item in every group using another static variable so I can easily figure out which group an item is in.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Right, but there is also step 6 that says: "Then, initialize the final class variables and fields of interfaces whose values are compile-time constant expressions"

Comment: The definition of [compile-time constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) excludes ++ as an operator in forming them.

Comment: If you try to run the code, it does the right thing i.e. `ITEM_GOLD == 0 && ITEM_ZINC == 1 && ITEM_TIN == 2` is true

Answer (score 0):

Although not a straight answer, it is the right one in my mind.
**try this and see, much faster to discover that way**
As for what values is a good approach, use enums or constants, makes it much more readable and maintainable.
Dynamic values might change in the future and give u unexpected results.

Comment: That advice always worries me unless it is very carefully circumscribed. Even in Java, there are areas, especially in connection with multi-threading, where something can appear to work in limited testing without being guaranteed to always work.

Comment: You never try? You ask first every time, even for simple stuff like the example above?

Comment: No, I very, very rarely need to ask. I read the JLS, the API javadocs, and other appropriate documentation. That way, I know what must always work in any valid implementation of the language.

Comment: Well.. I like to break things first, without asking permission and then check why it broke. I guess this is just different approcah, none is better than the other in my mind.

Comment: "Breaking things" is fine. If you try something and it does not work, that settles the issue. The dangerous case is assuming that something will always work based only on experiment, without theoretical support.

Comment: In the case above, that would have been enough.